# What is the name of this musical scale: E, F, G, G#, B, C#, D?

Tags: theory, scales

What is the name of this scale? As far as a root note goes, I think these three arrangements of it sound like they have a root.

- E, F, G, G#, B, C#, D...
- D, E, F, G, G#, B, C#...
- B, C#, D, E, F, G, G#...

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'll note that the G#s are probably A flats. You usually try to spell things so each pitch has a different letter name.

Comment: @AndyBonner And since G♯ and A♭ are not necessarily the same pitch.

Comment: @ElEctric - as far as this is concerned, G# and Ab will be deemed the same pitch.

Answer (score 7):

According to Ianring.com, and depending on the root:

- *Root = E*: [Kathian](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/1691). An Internet search suggests that this scale and its name only show up on scale-naming sites. No practical uses were found.
- *Root = D*: [Jeths' Mode](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/2669).

> This scale is named after Dutch composer Willem Jeths [1959–; [composer's website](https://www.willemjeths.com/)]. It is essentially a Diminished Scale omitting the augmented 5th. Strangely, there is no documentation of why this scale was named for Willem, but at some point it wandered onto a list of scales and has been canonized by repetition. (ianring.com)

- *Root = B*: [Moravian Pistalkova](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/877). This scale, like Kathian, seems to appear only on lists of scales.

All of these scales are related to what ianring.com calls Mela Ramapriya ([ianring.com](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/1747), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramapriya)), but which is also known as the Petrushka (Stravinsky) scale (for reasons unclear, but presumably related to the Petrushka chord [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrushka_chord)], which is a subset), and the Hungarian Major scale ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_major_scale)).

Comment: To spare readers some brainpower: The Petrushka chord rooted on G or C# is a subset because the OP's scale contains both of these major triads.

Comment: Thank you for responding! The scale works great over E7#9, 13 chord and harmonizing the whole thing out makes for some great chord progressions.

Comment: "Pistalkova" also appears in track 10 of this collection of Slovak folk music:  [Original Slovak Folk Music 2](https://www.warnerchappellpm.com/album/fontana-music-library-fn165/MTMzMTM4MS1lMWRhZTg).  Not sure if it's actually the same scale.

Answer (score 5):

You have here 7 out of 8 notes of the *octatonic* scale.  You can create this scale by alternating whole- and half-steps.  Related to @PiedPiper's answer, the octatonic scale is also the combination of all the notes in any two diminsihed-seventh chords.

For the present question, take the Edim7 and Fdim7 chords...

> E G Bb Db 
> F Ab B D 
>
> E - F - G - Ab - Bb - B - Db - D

You are missing only the Bb.

Also, because there are only seven letter names for the notes you will have to repeat one letter.

Answer (score 1):

The notes all fit a diminished scale (on D, F or G#) but missing A#(Bb).